# Jenkins groovy pipeline - git checkout error

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have defined a simple Jenkins pipeline using the Groovy DSL. My intention is that it will simply checkout my git repository.  However I am getting an error.

Given my groovy DSL defintion:

```
stage 'build'
node 
{
    git branch: '*/mybranch', credentialsId: 'my credentials', url: 'git@git.servername:pathto/myrepo.git'
}
```

I'm expecting the Jenkins pipeline to simply checkout my git repository.

However I'm getting the following error:

```
ERROR: Couldn't find any revision to build. Verify the repository and branch configuration for this job.
Finished: FAILURE
```

Can anyone help me in resolving this issue please?

Comment: Pipeline logs all specific git commands executed during checkout. I'd look into those looking for answers, comparing "short" and "full" output, for the start. It's difficult to suggest you anything better as your question relies on specific git repository setup, thus not reproducible

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The more verbose version works:

```
checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: '*/mybranch']], doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, extensions: [], submoduleCfg: [], userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: 'myCredentials', url: 'git@git.servername:pathto/myrepo.git']]])
```

However it would be nice to use the short-hand version.

Comment: Thanks for posting your solution.  This more verbose version worked for me.  using the shorthand, it just says `[Pipeline] tool` and then moves on to the next step, never cloning the repo.  But with the verbose version I see `[Pipeline] checkout
Cloning the remote Git repository` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Without the */ on the branch specifier works for me.

Try this:

```
git branch: 'mybranch', credentialsId: 'my credentials', url: 'git@git.servername:pathto/myrepo.git'
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Luke.  I've moved on from this project so I'm not in a position to easily verify, but maybe this can be helpful to others.  Although, I have a feeling my issue was with my git repo setup rather than Jenkins.